# Why my Visual Studio doesn't show HTML.*

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm begging with EpiServer and when I'm developing in a episerver project my VS2012 doesn't show the <% Html %> but it works very well and show many other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you should add its name space into the web.config of `Views` folder:

```
<namespaces>
    // ...
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    // ...
</namespaces>
```

Comment: Not. 
this is my web.config 
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

Comment: @Coelho - Did you add them to the main web.config too?

Comment: this is the copy of my main web.config

Comment: @Coelho - Main web.config isn't completely related to this issue. If want `@Html` methods in your views, you should add those namespaces to the inner web.config (which is located into the `Views` folder). If you also need HtmlHelper methods in your controllers, then you should add them into the main web.config

Comment: I understand you. I had in both and it doesn't result. And I create my html extensions and using import it works. :(